# How to return first 5 objects of Array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

In Swift, is there a clever way of using the higher order methods on Array to return the 5 first objects? 
The obj-c way of doing it was saving an index, and for-loop through the array incrementing index until it was 5 and returning the new array. Is there a way to do this with `filter`, `map` or `reduce`?

Comment: See [my answer for Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44931184/1966109) that shows up to 6 different ways to return the first `n` elements of an `Array`.

Answer (score 646, accepted):

By far the neatest way to get the first N elements of a Swift array is using `prefix(_ maxLength: Int)`:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
let slice5 = array.prefix(5) // ArraySlice
let array5 = Array(slice5)   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

the one-liner is:

```
let first5 = Array(array.prefix(5))
```

This has the benefit of being bounds safe. If the count you pass to `prefix` is larger than the array count then it just returns the whole array.

*NOTE:* as pointed out in the comments, `Array.prefix` actually returns an `ArraySlice`, not an `Array`.

If you need to assign the result to an `Array` type or pass it to a method that's expecting an `Array` param, you will need to force the result into an `Array` type: `let first5 = Array(array.prefix(5))`

Comment: +1 such a bad name choice, IMHO. Array has `dropFirst` and `dropLast`, so might as well have `takeFirst` and `takeLast`.

Comment: Also if you need `first5` to be an array, just write `let first5 = Array(someArray.prefix(5))`

Comment: @ULazdins no need for that. The return value of `someArray.prefix(5)` is already an `Array`. It couldn't be anything else!

Comment: @mluisbrown Sorry, can't agree with you :) In my project `video = video.prefix(5)` in Xcode 7.2 results in compile error  `Cannot assign value of type 'ArraySlice<Video>' to type '[Video]'`

Comment: @ULazdins my bad. You can use an `ArraySlice` pretty much as you would an `Array` though. Only direct assignment from one to the other needs explicit coercion. You can also do `video.prefix(5) + []` (adding forces coercion).

Comment: `video = Array(video.prefix(5))`

Comment: `prefix` seems to be iOS9+ only

Comment: @onmyway133 `prefix` is possibly Swift 2.x only (I don't remember if it was in 1.x), but it certainly exists in any OS that supports Swift 2.x, which is iOS 7 and above. Swift feature availability is determined by Swift releases, not iOS versions.

Answer (score 115):

You can do it really easy without `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, or `prefix` by just returning a range of your array via a subscript:

```
var wholeArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var n = 5

var firstFiveSlice = wholeArray[0..<n] // 1,2,3,4,5

let firstFiveArray = Array(firstFiveSlice)
```

Comment: If you want just the first `n` items from a Swift array you can do `wholeArray.prefix(n)` which has the added benefit of being bounds safe. If `n` is larger than the array size `prefix` returns the whole array.

Comment: It will crash if the `wholeArray` doesn't have more elements than `n`

Comment: @Crashalot I'm not entirely sure, but I think at the time, where I've written my answer, there was no such thing as `prefix`.

Comment: Use this code to get first 5 objects... This works perfectly

 **[0,1,2,3,4,5].enumerated().flatMap{ $0 < 5 ? $1 : nil }**

Answer (score 93):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you may choose one of the **6 following Playground codes** in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `subscript(_:)` subscript

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
let arraySlice = array[..<5]
//let arraySlice = array[0..<5] // also works
//let arraySlice = array[0...4] // also works
//let arraySlice = array[...4] // also works
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

---

### #2. Using `prefix(_:)` method

Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`; otherwise, O(*k*), where *k* is the number of elements to select from the beginning of the collection.

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
let arraySlice = array.prefix(5)
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Apple states for `prefix(_:)`:

> If the maximum length exceeds the number of elements in the collection, the result contains all the elements in the collection.

---

### #3. Using `prefix(upTo:)` method

Complexity: O(1)

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
let arraySlice = array.prefix(upTo: 5)
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Apple states for `prefix(upTo:)`:

> Using the `prefix(upTo:)` method is equivalent to using a partial half-open range as the collection's subscript. The subscript notation is preferred over `prefix(upTo:)`.

---

### #4. Using `prefix(through:)` method

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
let arraySlice = array.prefix(through: 4)
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

---

### #5. Using `removeSubrange(_:)` method

Complexity: O(*n*), where *n* is the length of the collection.

```
var array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
array.removeSubrange(5...)
print(array) // prints: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

---

### #6. Using `dropLast(_:)` method

Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`; otherwise, O(*k*), where k is the number of elements to drop.

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
let distance = array.distance(from: 5, to: array.endIndex)
let arraySlice = array.dropLast(distance)
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Answer (score 30):

```
let a: [Int] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
let b: [Int] = Array(a.prefix(5))
// result is [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 24):

**SWIFT 4**

*A different solution:*

An easy inline solution that wont crash if your array is too short

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5].enumerated().compactMap{ $0.offset < 3 ? $0.element : nil }
```

But works fine with this.

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5].enumerated().compactMap{ $0.offset < 1000 ? $0.element : nil }
```

Usually this would crash if you did this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5].prefix(upTo: 1000) // THIS CRASHES

[0,1,2,3,4,5].prefix(1000) // THIS DOESNT
```

Comment: for swift3 `[0,1,2,3,4,5].enumerated().flatMap{ $0.offset < 1000 ? $0.element : nil }`

Comment: Thanks! In case you want to update, flatMap is now called compactMap in Swift 4 for array compaction.

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 4**

To get the first N elements of a Swift array you can use `prefix(_ maxLength: Int)`:

```
Array(largeArray.prefix(5))
```

Answer (score 14):

For getting the first 5 elements of an array, all you need to do is slice the array in question. In Swift, you do it like this: `array[0..<5]`.

To make picking the N first elements of an array a bit more functional and generalizable, you could create an extension method for doing it. For instance:

```
extension Array {
    func takeElements(var elementCount: Int) -> Array {
        if (elementCount > count) {
            elementCount = count
        }
        return Array(self[0..<elementCount])
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) there are exist stock function ".prefix()" ; 2)will crash in case of 0 elements; 3) you create new array instead of ArraySlice, so it take more memory than it must to :)

Answer (score 9):

For an array of objects you can create an extension from Sequence.

```
extension Sequence {
    func limit(_ max: Int) -> [Element] {
        return self.enumerated()
            .filter { $0.offset < max }
            .map { $0.element }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Apple {}

let apples: [Apple] = [Apple(), Apple(), Apple()]
let limitTwoApples = apples.limit(2)

// limitTwoApples: [Apple(), Apple()]
```

Answer (score 5):

I slightly changed Markus' answer to update it for the latest Swift version, as `var` inside your method declaration is no longer supported:

```
extension Array {
    func takeElements(elementCount: Int) -> Array {
        if (elementCount > count) {
            return Array(self[0..<count])
        }
        return Array(self[0..<elementCount])
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)will crash in case 0 elements; 2) there are exist stock function ".prefix()" ; 3) you create new array instead of ArraySlice, so it take more memory than it must to :)

Answer (score 5):

Take this extension. It's fixing original horrible naming:

```
public extension Array {
    func first(_ count: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        return self.prefix(count)
    }
    
    func last(_ count: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        return self.suffix(count)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
someArr.first(5)
someArr.last(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Plain & Simple**

```
extension Array {
    func first(elementCount: Int) -> Array {
          let min = Swift.min(elementCount, count)
          return Array(self[0..<min])
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)will crash in case 0 elements; 2) there are exist stock function ".prefix()" ; 3) you create new array instead of ArraySlice, so it take more memory than it must to :)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4** with saving array types

```
extension Array {
    func take(_ elementsCount: Int) -> [Element] {
        let min = Swift.min(elementsCount, count)
        return Array(self[0..<min])
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)will crash in case 0 elements; 2) there are exist stock function ".prefix()" ; 3) you create new array instead of ArraySlice, so it take more memory than it must to :)

Answer (score 0):

The Prefix function is definitely the most efficient way of solving this problem, but you can also use for-in loops like the following:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let maxNum = 5
var iterationNumber = 0
var firstNumbers = [Int()]
if array.count > maxNum{
  for i in array{
    iterationNumber += 1
    if iterationNumber <= maxNum{
      firstNumbers.append(i)
    }
  }
  firstNumbers.remove(at: 0)
  print(firstNumbers)
} else {
  print("There were not \(maxNum) items in the array.")
}
```

This solution takes up many lines of code but checks to see if there are enough items in the array to carry out the program, *then* continues and solves the problem.
This solution uses many basic functions including `array.count`, which returns the amount of items in the array, **not the position of last item in the array**. It also uses `array.append`, which adds things onto the end of the array. Lastly, it uses `array.remove`, which removes the array's item that has a specified position.

I have tested it it and it works for at least swift 5.

Comment: there is exist stock func for arrays called ".prefix()" :)