# How to get first 20 items in pList dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to shuffle my arrays using the following extension:

```
extension Array {
var shuffled: [Element] {
    guard count > 1 else { return self }
    var elements = self
    for index in indices {
        let newIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(elements.count - index))) + index
        guard index != newIndex else { continue }
        swap(&elements[index], &elements[newIndex])
    }
    return elements
  }
}
```

I am then using this code to shuffle and get the first 20 items on my plist:

```
var questionsArray = [myPlistArray?.shuffled]
let shuffledQuestions = questionsArray.shuffle() // instance member cannot be used on type 'myViewController'
let first20 = questionsArray.prefix(20)
```

However, I always get this error:
// instance member cannot be used on type ‘myViewController’

Does anyone know how to do it right?
Or does anyone know how can I shuffle pList items and get the first 20 items?

My questions is quite the same with this one: [How to return first 5 objects of Array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527797/how-to-return-first-5-objects-of-array-in-swift), however, my data is in a plist dictionary file...

Anyways, my pList file is this: `myPlistArray.plist`

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 lines that are supposed to shuffle the array is jumbled and doesn't make much sense.

---

```
var questionsArray = [myPlistArray?.shuffled]
```

That line creates an array containing a single element, a shuffled version of myPlistArray. So you have an array within an array, which doesn't make sense.

---

```
let shuffledQuestions = questionsArray.shuffle() // instance member cannot be used on type 'myViewController'
```

That line tries to call a method `shuffle()` (not shuffled, shuffle, which doesn't exist) on the screwy `shuffledQuestions` array-within-array you created in the previous line.

---

```
let first20 = questionsArray.prefix(20)
```

That line would actually make sense if your first 2 lines were well formed.

You just want this:

```
let questionsArray = myPlistArray?.shuffled //Create a shuffled version
let first20 = questionsArray.prefix(20)  //take the first 20 items.
```

That code should work assuming that myPlistArray is an optional array.

Comment: It still shows like this: `let questionsArray = myPlistArray?.shuffled
let first20 = questionsArray.prefix(20) // instance member 'questionsArray' cannot be used on type 'myViewController'`

Comment: should I put the code in 'viewDidLoad'? If yes, how can I call it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You asked "should I put the code in 'viewDidLoad'?" There's no universal answer to where you should put that code. It depends on where you need it, which depends on what you want to do with it. I don't know enough about your needs to answer that. Then you asked: " If yes, how can I call it?" This question doesn't really make sense. If you put code in viewDidLoad, it gets run when viewDidLoad gets called by the system. You don't call it at all. Are you asking how you would get to the first20 array?

Comment: I used your code but it gives me the error // instance member 'questionsArray' cannot be used on type 'myViewController',

Comment: So edit your question to show the new code you've added. Show the whole method containing the code you've written, as well as the delcaration of the  instance variables that the code uses.