# Can't properly render data pulled from api in mapmarker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've done the application I'm making to swift with react native before, but I can't reach the result I want when creating a marker on a mapkit.

Instantly updated earthquakes are coming on Api, I want to show 100 of these earthquakes as markers. I did the display operation in the API, but the adjacent order created a diagonal marker.

I have a few questions for this project.

[my coding with React native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWSDZ.png)

[The screen I made on Android, the screen I wanted in swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT2NS.jpg)

[screen in Swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixADY.jpg)

**this is my code that i wrote in swift, i need some help i couldn't find any example about this issue. I hope you understand my problem.**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

struct MapAnnotationsView: View {
    
 @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9520281, longitude: 35.6980142), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 30, longitudeDelta: 10))

@State private var placeArray: [Place] = []


var body: some View {
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: placeArray) { annotation in
    // This makes a generic annotation that takes a View
    MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
        // This is your custom view
        AnnotationView(placeName: annotation.title)
    }
} .onAppear {
    Api().getEarthQuake { (quakes) in
        let tempArray = quakes.map{ quake in
                Place(title: "\(quake.yer)", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double.init(quake.enlem)!, longitude: Double.init(quake.enlem)!))
        }
        self.placeArray = tempArray
    }
}
}
}

struct AnnotationView: View {

let placeName: String
@State private var showPlaceName = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text(placeName)
                .font(.callout)
                .padding(15)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                // Prevents truncation of the Text
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                // Displays and hides the place name
                .opacity(showPlaceName ? 1 : 0)
        
        // You can use whatever you want here. This is a custom annotation marker
        // made to look like a standard annotation marker.
        Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        
        Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .offset(x: 0, y: -5)
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
            showPlaceName.toggle()
        }
    }
    
}
}

struct Place: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
var title: String
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

Comment: You are using the same thing (`quake.enlem`) for *both* latitude and longitude. Based on your React Native code (please include code, not pictures of code, which can't be searched, copied/pasted, or read by screen readers), it looks like longitude should be `quake.boylam`

Comment: omg, I've been researching for a word for about 4 hours :( so I want to ask again what is in the question I asked, how do I search it according to the first 100 api. I want to make a slice 100. @jnpdx

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means. Are you saying you only want to display the first 100 items from the API? That is likely something you'd want to handle in `Api`, which you haven't shown any code for. If you need to know how to get a slice of an array, you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527797/how-to-return-first-5-objects-of-array-in-swift

Comment: True, I want to show only the first 100 items. I did it this way in React native, but I can't do it while pulling data in swift. 

`const getEarth = async () => {
    const earth = await axios.get(earthURL);
    console.log(earth);
    setData(earth.data.slice(0,100));
    
  };`

Comment: Did you visit the link I sent? It shows multiple ways of slicing an array in Swift.

Comment: I just saw your edit, it worked for me. It's working. Thanks for your help. @jnpdx