# How to first 5 objects in Array with computed properties

Tags: arrays, swiftui

My project uses an array of computed properties (hourly wages) from which I need to isolate/return only the first 5 objects (wages) in the array. (Note: I have simplified my code for the purpose of isolating this problem, but in so doing it may seem strange that this array is a computed property and not simply a variable.  Please accept this oddity as it is necessary in my more complex, complete code.)

Research effort: [The Apple Documentation "prefix(upTo:)"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/prefix(upto:)?changes=_4) would seemingly be a perfect fit for this task.  I have referenced the [SO question that was asked 7 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527797/how-to-return-first-5-objects-of-array-in-swift), but when I apply all the recommendations of all 13 answers, I still get the following errors:

[image]

Here is my code with a variety of approaches attempting to accomplish the same result:

```
class EarningsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var catWageArray: [Double] {
        [81,156,162,166,169,173,177,181,185,192,277,280,282,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285]
    }

    var sliceCareerTest =  catWageArray.prefix(5)
    var sliceCareerTest2 =  catWageArray.prefix(upTo: 5)
    var sliceCareer: [Double] {
        catWageArray.prefix(5)}
    var sliceCareer2: [Double] {
        catWageArray.prefix(upTo: 5)}
    
    var n = 5
    var firstFiveSlice = catWageArray[0..<n]
    let firstFiveArray = Array(firstFiveSlice)
```

It seems to me that the sliceCareer computed property with the error "No 'prefix' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '[Double]'" may be the closest to the actual solution, but I don't understand why there the compiler cannot find prefix candidates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is `prefix(5)` but you have to create an array from the slice (aka `SubSequence`) and it must be a computed property.

On the other hand `catWageArray` can be a stored property

```
class EarningsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var catWageArray: [Double] = [81,156,162,166,169,173,177,181,185,192,277,280,282,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285,285]
    
    
    var sliceCareer: [Double] {
        Array(catWageArray.prefix(5))
    }
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  You're my hero!
Follow-up question: 
If I want to remove the first 5 instead of isolate, I've tried using "catWageArray.removeSubrange(0..<5)" but get the following 2 errors: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'catWageArray' is a get-only property" & "Type '()' cannot conform to 'Sequence'"
Feel free to respond with an another "Answer" so I can mark it as "accepted" and "useful"

Comment: This is simply `Array(catWageArray.dropFirst(5))`. `removeSubrange` mutates the receiver in place and it works if you follow my suggestion to declare `catWageArray` as stored property.